# iOS - Listing directories/files at given url using NSURLSession and dataTaskWithRequest?

Tags: ios, parsing, ftp, directory, nsdata

I am trying to connect to a media server via NSURLSession and list all available directories/files at that url ***(i.e. ftp://mediaServer.local)***, then traverse down them until I find the file I am looking for.

I am able to provide a url and spit out it's top level files/directories  using 'dataTaskWithRequest', but the parsed NSData is not really readable so that I can actually append the file/directory to the original URL and then traverse down the path.

Here is what is spit out:

```
Results: drwxrwsr-x   11 65534    65534       65536 Sep 19 15:36 Public
```

The directory I would then want to traverse into is the 'Public' directory, so the url I want to use next should be ***ftp://mediaServer.local/Public/***.

How can I parse the NSData object to be easier to just get the actual names of all readable files/directories? 
I tried parsing the NSData result into a JSON dictionary, but that doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
// Url used = ftp://mediaServer.local/
func startRequestWithUrl(url: NSURL)
{
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        print("Data: \(data)")
        print("Response: \(response)")
        print("Error: \(error)")

        if let data = data, let results = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        {
            print("Results: \(results)")

            do
            {
                let dict = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments) as? NSDictionary
                print("Dict: \(dict)")
            }
            catch let caught as NSError
            {
                print("Caught: \(caught)")
            }
            catch
            {
                // Something else happened.
                print("Error parsing data.")
            }
        }

    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**UPDATE:**

With the below answer, I tried spitting out each file/directory into a single string and break it up into an array, but it doesn't seem to break the components apart properly as I only get single-item arrays with the full file path string still.

Code:

```
if let data = data, let results = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
        {
            print("Results: \(results)")
            let lines = results.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
            for line in lines
            {
                let fields = line.componentsSeparatedByString("\t")
                print("Line: \(line) - Fields: \(fields)")
            }
        }
```

Results:

```
Results: drwxrwsr-x   11 65534    65534       65536 Sep 19 15:36 Public

Line: drwxrwsr-x   11 65534    65534       65536 Sep 19 15:36 Public
- Fields: ["drwxrwsr-x   11 65534    65534       65536 Sep 19 15:36 Public\r"]
Line:  - Fields: [""]
```

Comment: A couple problems: it looks like you should be separating lines on `\r\n` instead of just `\n`. This will change from one FTP server to the next. It's pretty clear `\t` is not being used anywhere. Instead you'll want scan each line using `NSScanner`, to split it up based on whitespace character sets (until the last column, where you'll scan until the end of the line including whitespace). Since you're using `NSScanner` anyway, you should probably use it to split up lines as well. `NSScanner` is very fast and memory efficient, it will handle large directories better than componentsSeparatedBy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results are just a text directory list, just parse the text. You can use `componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n:` to get an array of entries. For each entry you can use `componentsSeparatedByString:@" :` (possibly @"\t") to get the file name.

Directories can be determined by the first letter "d".

You will want to ignore certain files and directories of course.

Other methods include regular expressions and `NSScanner`.
You will want to ignore certain files and directories of course.

This is all rather simple parsing.

Comment: Thanks! Any chance you have a simple example of how I would parse to just get the directory name? I want to make sure it would be able to get a file/directory name properly no matter what other text might be spit out, so don't want to depend on a magic number of 'entries' if I use an array.

Comment: You need to try. If you re having trouble with the code add it to the question and you should get help.

Comment: Ok updated the code. It doesn't seem to break up the string into a proper array. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are going to have to examine the code for the correct separators. For me the best way is to look at a hex dump, add one the the question.